# Fitting multivariate mixed model (mvglmer) with JMBayes - Error in x$terms : object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable

Tags: r, lme4, glmm

I am trying to do a `mvglmer` fit with `jmbayes` with the following snippet data of the first patient:

```
****id1     predx**    
1011025 Prednisolone        
               
**wks ecgrate_binary ecgpri_binary** 
  0              1                 0
```

Here is the code:

```
mvFit1 <-  mvglmer(ecgrate_binary ~treatment+ time+(time|id),
                   ecgpri_binary ~treatment+time +(1|id),
                   data = my_df, 
                   families = list(binomial(link = "logit", binomial(link = "logit"),
                   engine ="STAN")
```

Which produces the error

> Error in x$terms : object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable

In my data, I have repeated measurements for each patient, which are binary coded as 0 or 1 (i.e.`ecgrate_binary`, `ecgpri_binary`).

I have browsed stackoverflow and found similar issues; however, I have not been able to solve the problem. I, unfortunately, can't provide the link to the data as this is for my thesis.

Comment: The following link provides methods on how to create a reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: are you missing a closing parenthesis in the `families` argument e.g. should it be                    `families = list(binomial(link = "logit"), binomial(link = "logit"))`

Comment: should the two formulas be in a `list` ; according to the help page https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/JMbayes/html/mvglmer.html

Comment: @user20650 my mistake when i was posting the question. I still have the same error even when I put the formulas in a list